# How to handle X-CSRF-Token for jQuery POST in UI5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I want to use jQuery POST method to call an xsjs service that does some modifications in Database.My xsaccess file prevents xsrf, so  I need to handle it in my controller method.

Below is my controller code-

```
    var obj= {};
          obj.name= "John";
          obj.age= "abc@xyz.com";
          obj.loc= "Minnesota";

    jQuery.ajax({
            url: "serviceTest.xsjs",
            type: "GET",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch");
            },
            success: function(responseToken, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        var token = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token');         
                console.log("token = " +token);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "serviceTest.xsjs",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                    },
                    success : function(response) {
                         // will be called once the xsjs file sends a  
                            response
                         console.log(response);

                     },
                     error : function(e) {
                         // will be called in case of any errors:
                         var errMsg = e.responseText
                         console.log(e);

                     }
                });
            },
```

And here is my xsjs code-

```
    var csrf_token = $.request.headers.get("X-CSRF-Token");
    if(csrf_token === "Fetch") {
    var content = $.request.body.asString();
    var args = $.parseJSON(content);

    var xsName= args.name;
    var xsemail= args.email;
    var xsLoc= args.loc;
   //then execute DML statement  by passing these 3 parameters as arguments.
    catch (error) {
            $.response.setBody(content);   
            $.response.status = $.net.http.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;   
    }
```

I am not able to do the update and getting error Err 500 - Internal server Error.
Any suggestions would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

---

Edit:

If I forgot the token then I got a 403 Access denied error ("CSRF token validation failed") and not a 500 internal. So I think something is wrong with your services

---

You can add your X-CSRF-Token as header of your POST request with setup your ajax requests before your fire your POST.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': token
    }
});

jQuery.ajax({
                url: "serviceTest.xsjs",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
```

Otherwise add it to each POST request.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "serviceTest.xsjs",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                headers: {
                   'X-CSRF-Token': token
                },
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
```

Your way with using beforeSend event should work too.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: sorry for that.